# Postgresql - jsonb How to find jsonpath of attributes retreived using wildcard path and jsonb_path_query

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

I am using PostgreSQL ( 13.6 ).  We have a json and and the same attribute name is in many places, like `Code`. The table has a key - polnum and a json for each polnum. I am able to get all values of Code using the wildcard jsonpath `jsonb_path_query(payload, '$.**.Code'`.  But I would also like to find and display the path of the attribute.  I was trying to figure out if I could use the jsonb_extract_path, but could not make it work.

Here is my sample json value

```
WITH json_table AS (
        SELECT 'PL123456' as polnum, '
        {
        "node1": { 
            "node2": { 
                "node3": [ 
                    {
                        "node4": { 
                            "node5": { 
                                "Code": "34",
                                "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                                "System": "2",
                                "PercentageAddup": "True"
                            }
                        },
                        "node6": { 
                            "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000033",
                            "UserID": "WebServices",
                            "PartyID": "cc6ef1d8-d0ad-4044-9bd8-6c34c16eec5f",
                            "Percentage": "1.00"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "node4": { 
                            "node5": { 
                                "Code": "32",
                                "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                                "System": "2",
                                "PercentageAddup": "False"
                            }
                        },
                        "node6": { 
                            "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000118",
                            "UserID": "WebServices",
                            "PartyID": "10d8e781-a4d7-4a17-a4a0-eb7ac71b75b4",
                            "Percentage": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "node7": [ 
                {
                    "node8": { 
                        "node9": { 
                            "Code": "8",
                            "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                            "System": "2",
                            "PercentageAddup": "True"
                        }
                    },
                    "node10": { 
                        "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000143",
                        "UserID": "WebServices",
                        "PartyID": "10d8e781-a4d7-4a17-a4a0-eb7ac71b75b4",
                        "Relationship": "Self"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node8": { 
                        "node9": { 
                            "Code": "31",
                            "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                            "System": "2",
                            "PercentageAddup": "False"
                        }
                    },
                    "node10": { 
                        "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000156",
                        "UserID": "WebServices",
                        "PartyID": "10d8e781-a4d7-4a17-a4a0-eb7ac71b75b4",
                        "Relationship": "Self"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "node11": { 
                "node12": { 
                    "node13": { 
                        "Code": "38",
                        "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                        "System": "2",
                        "PercentageAddup": "False"
                    }
                },
                "node14": { 
                    "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000170",
                    "UserID": "WebServices",
                    "Percentage": "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    '::JSONB AS payload
    )
    select polnum, jsonb_path_query(payload, 'strict $.**.Code') from json_table
```

This is the output

```
PL123456    "34"
PL123456    "32"
PL123456    "8"
PL123456    "31"
PL123456    "38"
```

The query I tried to get the path for each of the Code values

```
select polnum, 
       jsonb_path_query(payload, 'strict $.**.Code'), 
       jsonb_extract_path(jsonb_path_query(payload, 'strict $.**.Code'), 'Code') 
from json_table
```

Here I expected to get the jsonpath for each Code value I received. But it returns

[image]

Is it possible ?  How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: I fail to see how the "Output" relates to the JSON data you posted. Also is that your current output? Or your desired output? And what is the SQL code that you tried but failed to get working?

Comment: Updated the question with details

Comment: @Bergi and other experts - Is it possible?  How do I go about it?  What is wrong in the approach I have taken ?

Comment: Is it not possible?  Are the moderators ok with me putting this question on dba forum or will someone flag it as a cross-post even though this issue is not resolved in more than a month of posting?  Just hoping to get some traction